# Make a glider-element draggable in JSXGraph

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

I want to allow a glider-element that originally moves along a line A, to be dragged to another line B. After the glider-element is dragged to the new line, it should function as a glider on the new line.

What's the best way to implement this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be realized with *magnetized points*. A JSXGraph point might receive the array attribute `attractors`. This makes the point  a glider in case it is close enough to one of the attractor elements. "Close enough" is determined by the attribute `attractorDistance`. The point can be made "free" again by dragging it off of the object. The amount of dragging is determined by the attribute `snatchDistance`. Here is an example with a snatchDistance that makes it impossible to drag the point off of the lines:

```
var line1 = board.create('line', [[-4,4], [4,1]]);
var line2 = board.create('line', [[-4,1], [4,2]]);
var p = board.create('point', [4,1], {
    attractors: [line1, line2], 
    attractorDistance: 0.5, 
    snatchDistance: 1000
});
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/dcf2o85j/2/. Another example is at https://jsxgraph.org/wiki/index.php/Magnetized_points.